# Dynamic list of dropdownlists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm working on my first MVC project and I wanted to see if there's a better way to do this. I'm pretty sure there is.

I'm building an application for audits. Each audit has a list of questions, and each question has a list of options to select from. The questions and options can change. So, I have to dynamically build the table of questions and the dropdowns with the question's options.

Here's how I'm creating the SelectLists in the controller

```
foreach (var r in employeeAuditData.Audit.AuditResults)
{
    ViewData["Result" + r.AuditQuestionID] =
       new SelectList(r.AuditQuestion.QuestionOptions, "QuestionOptionID", "OptionText", r.QuestionOption);
}
```

And here's the code for my view

```
foreach (var r in Model.Audit.AuditResults.OrderBy(r => r.AuditQuestion.Ordinal).ToList())
{
    <tr>
        <td>@r.AuditQuestion.QuestionText</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("Result" + r.AuditQuestionID, "(Select)")</td>
    </tr>
}
```

This works but using concatenation for the ViewData key seems like a funky way to do this. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about making a ViewModel?

```
class AuditResultSelectList
{
    int QuestionId { get; set;}
    SelectList QuestionOptions { get; set;}
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
List<AuditResultSelectList> list = new List<AuditResultSelectList>();

foreach (var r in employeeAuditData.Audit.AuditResults)
{
    AuditResultSelectList a = new AuditResultSelectList()
    {
        QuestionId = r.AuditQuestionID,
        QuestionOptions = new SelectList(r.AuditQuestion.QuestionOptions, "QuestionOptionID", "OptionText", r.QuestionOption)
    }

    list.Add(a);
}

ViewData["QuestionSelectLists"] = list;
```

Then your view can pull the list out using:

```
var x = (List<AuditResultSelectList>) ViewData["QuestionSelectLists"];
```

Comment: i'll just need to make some changes to the view model, but this will definitely work. thanks internet stranger!